# ImportError: No module named flask.ext.login even though Flask is installed

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I have installed Flask with:

```
pip install flask-debugtoolbar==0.10.0
```

When I `import flask` in Python, it works, but when I do `import flask.ext.login`, I get

```
ImportError: No module named flask.ext.login
```

Why can't I import this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't installed Flask-Login.  When you installed Flask-DebugToolbar, Flask got installed automatically as a required dependency. Flask-Login is an independent extension to Flask, and isn't required by that package.

Install it with

```
pip install flask-login
```

Then import it with

```
import flask_login
```

You can list all installed modules with `pip list`.